# Is there a way to generate programmatically some javascript code to execute in the Chrome or Firefox debugger?

Tags: javascript, browser, controls

This would prove very useful for automating testing, but not limited to that. I wonder if some mainstream browser has a feature or extension allowing to control the browser using plain javascript to be executed in the debugger sandbox. I can't see such option in the command line help for firefox or chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd want something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Will Selenium work with those pages whose html is partly or entirely generated dynamically using JavaScript in result of user interactions?

Comment: Yes, Selenium will read whatever the current DOM is. You can create Selenium "scripts" that automate user actions, thus potentially causing the contents of the page to change.

Answer (score 0):

use [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) (a Firefox plugin) and if you are good with programming then Selenium [WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) is one of the best options ever, using it you can deal with the browser using C#, or Java code, it supports other known languages.

Here is some lines of c# code that shows you how great Selenium is (this code can test a login page):

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Drivers");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.website/login");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("username");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("password");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();
```

Comment: I wonder if Selenium allows me to execute arbitrary Javascript code. If so, I could just use the standard JavaScript API with it instead of having to learn the Selenium one.

Comment: Selenium uses Javascript to talk to the browsers, I guess you can not use your own javascript code.

Comment: Yes, Selenium is easy, but we would not need it if only the browser was scriptable. Browsers are quite conservative in this regard. They do not even allow to change a Javascript file on the fly, without reloading the page, which I often needed for testing and debugging.